# mock axios react testing library jest

Tags: reactjs, axios, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

Below is code for cascading two dropdowns using react. I am trying to write ut for this. I am trying to mock axios call.when i do expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) it actually gives 0. can someone please help

```
<div className="fixed-layout">
                <Row align="bottom">
                    <Col span={4} className="mr-15">
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Item label="Tag Group">
                                <Selectbox
                                    showSearch
                                    style={{ width: 200 }}
                                    placeholder="Select tag group"
                                    optionFilterProp="children"
                                    value={tagList}
                                    id="tagGroup"
                                    data-testid= "tagGroupTest"
                                    data-cy="tag-list"
                                    filterOption={(input, option) =>
                                        option.props.children
                                            .toLowerCase()
                                            .indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                                    }
                                    changed={(value) => {
                                        setTagList(value);
                                        setSearchTagGroup(value);
                                        setTagValueList(tagValuesMap[value]);
                                        setTagValue("");
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <Select.Option value="" data-testid ="Select">
                                        Select
                                    </Select.Option>
                                
                                    {tagValuesMap &&
                                        Object.keys(tagValuesMap).length > 0 &&
                                        Object.keys(tagValuesMap).map((type) => (
                                            <Select.Option
                                                value={type}
                                                key={type}
                                                data-testid={type}
                                            >
                                                {type}
                                            </Select.Option>
                                        ))}
                                </Selectbox>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={6} className="ml-15">
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Item label="Tag Value">
                            <Selectbox
                                    showSearch
                                    style={{ width: 200 }}
                                    placeholder="Select tag value"
                                    optionFilterProp="children"
                                    value={tagValue}
                                    id="tagValue"
                                    data-cy="tagvalue-list"
                                    data-testid="tagValueTest"
                                    filterOption={(input, option) =>
                                        option.props.children
                                            .toLowerCase()
                                            .indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                                    }
                                    changed={(value) => {
                                        setTagValue(value);
                                        setSearchTagValue(value);
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <Select.Option value="">
                                        Select
                                    </Select.Option>
                                    {tagValuesList &&
                                        tagValuesList.length > 0 &&
                                        tagValuesList.map((type) => (
                                            <Select.Option
                                                value={type}
                                                key={type}
                                            >
                                                {type}
                                            </Select.Option>
                                        ))}
                                </Selectbox>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={2} align="bottom">
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Item>
                            <div  style={{height:"40px"}}></div>
                            <Button type="primary" id='search' data-cy ="searchbtn" data-testid='search' onClick={handleSearch}>Search</Button>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="fright mt-20">
                        <div
                            id="components-dropdown-demo-dropdown-button"
                            className="fleft"
                        >
                            <Dropdown overlay={downloadMenu}>
                                <Button data-cy="download-template-btn">
                                    <Link href="#">
                                        <a>Download Template</a>
                                    </Link>
                                    <Icon type="down" />
                                </Button>
                            </Dropdown>
                        </div>
                        <Dropdown overlay={uploadMenu}>
                            <Button data-cy="upload-tag-btn">
                                <Link href="#">
                                    <a>Create New Tags</a>
                                </Link>
                                <Icon type="down" />
                            </Button>
                        </Dropdown>

                        
                    </Col>
                </Row>
```

Below is handleSearch function:

```
 const handleSearch = async () => {
        console.log("inside handle search");
        if (searchTagGroup == ""  && searchTagValue == "") {
            return;
        }
        let param = {};
        if (searchTagValue !== "") {
            param.tagValue = searchTagValue;
        }
        if (searchTagGroup !== "") {
            param.tagGroup = searchTagGroup;
        }
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(param);
        let response = await service.getTags(searchParams.toString());
        setSelectedTagsList(response.content);
    };
```

My unit test :

```
        axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ status: 200, data: {content: {tagsApi}} }));
        getTags.mockResolvedValueOnce(tagsApi);
        window.localStorage.setItem("authenticated", "true");
        const {getByRole , getByText, getByTestId} = render(
            <Provider store={store}>
            <Tags
            data={tags}
            tagValuesMap={tagValuesMap}
            tagtypes={tagtypes}
            />
            </Provider>
        ); 
        const handleSearch = async () => {
            console.log("inside handle search");
            if (searchTagGroup == ""  && searchTagValue == "") {
                return;
            }
            let param = {};
            if (searchTagValue !== "") {
                param.tagValue = searchTagValue;
            }
            if (searchTagGroup !== "") {
                param.tagGroup = searchTagGroup;
            }
            const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(param);
            let response = await service.getTags(searchParams.toString());
            setSelectedTagsList(response.content);
        };
        fireEvent.click(document.querySelectorAll(".ant-select-search__field")[0]);         
        fireEvent.change(document.querySelectorAll(".ant-select-search__field")[0],{target: { value: "itemdish" },});
        expect(document.querySelectorAll(".ant-select-search__field")[0].value).toBe('itemdish');
        fireEvent.click(document.querySelectorAll(".ant-select-search__field")[1]);
        fireEvent.change(document.querySelectorAll(".ant-select-search__field")[1],{target: { value: "fries" },});  
        expect(document.querySelectorAll(".ant-select-search__field")[1].value).toBe('fries');
        fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('search')); 
        expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        await expect(getByTestId('recordCount').textContent).toBe("1 records");
        screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL();
    });
```

expect(axios.get) gives 0 times called. Can someone please help.

Comment: can you try putting "await" for search click i.e. line "        fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('search'));", 
it might be taking some time to fire api request

Comment: Also put one console log inside "service.getTags" function which I assume is making the real api call via axios in order to verify the flow.
Because there are chances that handleSearch can return early without making any api call.

Answer (score 0):

after putting log in handleSearch, I found that handleSearch is returning early by this case:

```
if (searchTagGroup == ""  && searchTagValue == "") {
```

Hence the api will not be called in handleSearch is not called and expectation of `axios.get` call will fail because no calls were made so count will be `0`.